# Php-html document does not load bootstrap and css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I have an application written in php that works within a worpress site as a plugin.
This application is located inside the wp-content / plugin folder and is called SW.
Inside the folder there is the index.php file and the relative folders with bootstrap and css, but when I recall them from the index.php file they are not loaded on the browser but the html and the whole application work.
To recall them I use the codes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap4/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

<script src="bootstrap4/other/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="bootstrap4/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="include/css/stili-custom.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="funzioni.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "funzioni_tour.js"></script>
...
```

If, on the other hand, I use CND, then I call bootstrap through the links, everything works but I still can't connect my personal css style sheets.
I also specify that before being a wordpress plugin, this application worked on its own.
So it was copied and moved inside plugins and my feeling is that the code is looking for styles in the wrong folders.
I use filezilla FTP software to connect to the server.
Could anyone explain to me why these stylesheets are not loaded?

Comment: Thank You for the edit, I didn't understand why he didn't take the codes

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Does loading the linked files causes a 404 error, or anything related? Is this really related to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your main file: [plugin-name].php:

```
<?php
function sw_add_styles_scripts() {
 //register scripts
wp_register_script('bootstrap_script', plugins_url('/bootstrap4/js/bootstrap.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),false, true);
wp_register_script('bootstrap_script-ui', plugins_url('/bootstrap4/other/jquery-ui.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),false, true);

//enqueue scripts
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_script');
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_script-ui');

//enqueue styles
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap4/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/include/css/stili-custom.css' );
}
  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sw_add_styles_scripts' );  
?>
```

For more info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/,
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/